# Reading a string in C until an integer is encountered (in file)

Tags: c

How can I read a string in C until I encounter an integer? For example:
1000 Ball pen 12 15 24
I need to separate "Ball pen" from the integers. How is it done?

Comment: Crude method: Loop over the string and compare with ASCII codes

Comment: If you read that string **until** you encounter an integer, then you should stop right at the beginning. Try to define your problem more clearly. For example, if you have "1000 Ball 12 pen 15 25", do you expect "Ball" as output or "Ball pen"?

Comment: It depends on how integers are delimited. Are there two integers in `1,2`? In `1abc2`? What about this string: `1.0e2`, how many integers are there?

Comment: @Shahbaz, If he reads the string until he encounters an integer, wouldn't the output for his example would be NULL since the first word is an integer?

Comment: @AnishRam, that's what I said: _... then you should stop right at the beginning_. More precisely though, the output would be `""`, which is an empty string. After that, I assumed he would want to pass over the initial numbers (based on his example) and hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

The way *I* would do it would probably be to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to get the whole line, then parse it manually doing something like:

1. Read the initial integer. This can easily be done with e.g. [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul).
2. Read the characters while they are not digits (using [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit)).
3. Do `strtoul` in a loop until you have all numbers.